# Detecting redirect to a different URL

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, response.redirect

I am using ASP.NET MVC with AngularJs framework. In my home controller I'm checking if there is a valid license and if not, I'm re-directing to a page to import license with this code:

```html
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var retVal = _licenseProvider.ValidateExistingLicense();

            if (!retVal.Item1)
            {                
                Response.Redirect("DataMaintenance/ImportLicenses", true);
                return View("DataMaintenance/ImportLicenses");
            }
```

So, in my ImportLicenses controller I want to detect that I was re-directed vs. called from the menu. I found an older thread about redirecting to a different action, but that solution doesn't apply. What are my options here?

Comment: May I ask why you are using Response.Redirect instead of Response.RedirectToAction?

Comment: Because it's a different controller in a different aread

Comment: You can use RedirectToAction to redirect to different areas too: `return RedirectToAction("Index", "ImportLicenses", new { area = "DataMaintenance" }`

Comment: Sounds good, perhaps I should have employed this solution instead. I was just trying to work with the existing code, which is quite complex and doesn't really work the way we need anyway. In other words, if the license is not valid, we want to prevent an access. We display a modal dialog, but it can be easily escaped.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it doesn't work, e.g. the result is not detected as being the result of redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile I decided to do a little bit of cheating, but it worked. In the menu I changed the original call to this

```html
 dataMaintNodes.SubNodes.Add(new MenuMapNode() { LabelKey = "importLicense", Action = "ImportLicenses", Controller = "ImportLicenses", Area = "DataMaintenance", Icon = "", Roles = "IMPORTLIC" });
```

In other words, instead of normal Index action I introduced a different action. I added that new action to my controller and just set the ViewBag property to false when called from the menu and to true in the Index action that is called by Redirect. So, it's a cheating, but it works. I only wanted to display Cancel button on that modal dialog when I am calling from the regular menu and no Cancel button when called from the home controller. Now, my second problem is that Modal Dialog doesn't really prevent from escaping from it and continuing working with the application. So, we may want to introduce more logic.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here:

1. Add a query string parameter in the ImportLicenses action that
   determines whether the user got here via a redirect or the menu
2. Set a `TempData` variable before redirecting your user to the
       ImportLicenses action.
3. Use a `Session` variable

[Read this for more information about passing data between Action methods.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your constraints, there are a number of options.  Without knowing much about your project. My first suggestion would be to drop a cookie before redirecting, then when the request comes in to the ImportLicenses action you can check for the check, and delete it, but include whether or not the cookie was found in your view model so you can reflect this in the UI.

There are other options like using session state, or a query string parameter.  A querystring parameter could be just as effective as the cookie idea i mentioned above, and it would be a bit cleaner.

If you can provide more information about your use case, I may be able to expand my answer.

Hope this helps.